# Fading an array of strings in and out

Tags: ios, swift, label, fade

Using swift i am able to get the words "Hello, World" to fade in and out every 2 seconds with a 3 second delay.

**What is the best way to get multiple strings (5-8) to fade in and out repeatedly one at a time?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?   I would use an array of strings and change the text each time the fade out finished before fading it in.

Comment: @Paulw11 ` override func viewDidLoad() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.factsLabel.alpha = 0
            }) { (success) -> Void in
                self.factsLabel.alpha = 1
        }
    }
`

Comment: @Paulw11 i am able to get the Label to fade briefly for 1 second. Then it comes back, My goal is to have multiple strings fade in and out at different times. Any ideas? Can't i just set 'label.text = "String 1"' then do 'label.text = "String 2"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a pair of nested animations, one to handle the fade in and the other to handle the fade out.  You can call the second in the completion block of the first.

Then you need to change the message and then animate the new message, which is simply calling the animation pair again.  Here is one way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    let theMessages=["Message 1","Message 2","The third message","The final message"]
    var messageIndex=0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.label.text=""
        self.label.alpha=0;
        self.animateMessage()
    }

    func animateMessage() {
        self.label.text=self.theMessages[self.messageIndex];
        if (++self.messageIndex == self.theMessages.count) {
            self.messageIndex=0;
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.label.alpha=1.0
            }, completion: { (success) -> Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.label.alpha=0
                    }, completion: { (success) -> Void in
                        self.animateMessage()
                })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Paul, I noticed when i change VC's then go back to the one with the array of strings fading. It speeds up extremely fast, Anyway to remedy this?

Comment: Move the call to animateMessage() to viewDidLoad from viewWillAppear

Comment: I did last night after asking. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In a variation of the accepted answer, whenever you find yourself nesting animations, you can often use a keyframe animation:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

let messages = ["Message 1", "Message 2", "The third message", "The final message"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    changeTextForLabel(label, index: 0)
}

func changeTextForLabel(label: UILabel, index: Int) {
    label.text = messages[index]
    label.alpha = 0

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: [], animations:
        {
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.2) { label.alpha = 1 }
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.8, relativeDuration: 0.2) { label.alpha = 0 }
        }, completion: { [weak self] finished in
            let nextIndex = index + 1
            self?.changeTextForLabel(label, index: nextIndex < self?.messages.count ? nextIndex : 0)
        })
}
```

Or, if rather than fading out, you'd rather have a nice cross-dissolve between the values, you can do something like:

```
func changeTextForLabel(label: UILabel, index: Int) {
    UIView.transitionWithView(label, duration: 3.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:
        {
            self.label.text = self.messages[index]
        }, completion: { [weak self] finished in
            let nextIndex = index + 1
            self?.changeTextForLabel(label, index: nextIndex < self?.messages.count ? nextIndex : 0)
        })
}
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not asking you to change your accepted answer, but just showing you an alternative.